# Opening the excel file extracted from SAP

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

This is the error message while opening the excel file extracted from SAP

[image: error on opening the excel file]

and this is the run time error

[image: the last time you opened it caused a serious error]

How can I open by VBA the file concerning above errors.
The line with the error below

```
If Not Dir(path & name, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
  Dim wB1 As Workbook
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet

  With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
  End With

  Set wB1 = Workbooks.Open(path & name)          'this is the error line
    
  Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")
  Workbooks(name).Activate
```

Comment: show us content of `path` and `name` variable

Comment: In fact VBA opens the excel files in the loop. Some of them macro can open, and some can't. Below the variables
```Dim path As String
    path = Cells(2, 6)```
F2 - C:\Users\kamil\Desktop\invoice\

```Dim name As String
name = Cells(a, 1) & ".xlsx"```
a1 - number of the order e.g.615608

Comment: You determine format of file as `".xlsx"` try change this to `"*.*"` then macro try open all files. you can add error handler if occurs. and change `Workbooks(name).Activate` to `wb1.activate` if you rly need to activate :)